# Open problems in Functions of One Complex Variable?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, open-problem, research

I am interested in complex variables, and only have knowledge for one variable, not several as of now... Regardless, I want to participate in some research... Do you guys know of any interesting open problems in one complex variable?

Comment: RH is one such problem.

Comment: @sku A bit above me level to be honest... RH is way too difficult.

Comment: I was being facetious. Seriously though, pick up any intro book on complex analysis/variables and you will find tons of problems.

Comment: @sku where should I look in those books?

Comment: At the end of each chapter.